# link my XML file to my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I need some help on JavaScript, I have created a XML file I would like for it to be displayed in my HTML page that I also created.I would like this to be displayed on the browser in the following manner inside a Div element with the help of JavaScript :

---

```
items
   |
   |__fruits
   |    |_____orange
   |    |_____Banana
   |    |_____Mango
   |
   |__drinks
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items image="images/items.JPG">
  <fruits image="images/fruits.JPG">
    <orange  image="images/orange.JPG" qty="15" rate="Rs 40/kg"/>
    <banana  image="images/banana.JPG" qty="25" rate="Rs 20/kg"/>
    <mango  image="images/mango.JPG" qty="19" rate="Rs 45/kg"/>
  </fruits>
  <drinks  image="images/drinks.jpg">
    <pepsi image="images/pepsi.jpg" qty="10" rate="Rs 22/litre"/>
    <coke image="images/coke.jpg" qty="8" rate="Rs 21/litre"/>
    <wines image="images/wines.JPG">
      <grapes  image="images/grapes.JPG" qty="4" rate="Rs 60/litre"/>
      <apple  image="images/apple.JPG" qty="2" rate="Rs 80/litre"/>
    </wines>
    <harddrinks image="images/harddrinks.JPG">
      <whisky  image="images/whisky.JPG" qty="3" rate="Rs 100/litre"/>
      <beer  image="images/beer.JPG" qty="3" rate="Rs 30/litre"/>
    </harddrinks>
  </drinks>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse through the XML file to suit your specific needs, but maybe start by loading in the xml file:

```
var xmlDoc;
<!--
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
else // Internet Explorer 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","PathToYourXMLFilename.xml",false);
xhttp.send("");
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
```

Then place each node element into an array (or several):

```
var myFruits=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fruits");
```

Can i get more simpler method to browse through all the node

```
    var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('data.xml');
var myItems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("items");
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("dvList1");

var divOutput = document.createElement("div");
var divstr = document.createTextNode(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName);
divOutput.appendChild(divstr);
outputDiv.appendChild(divOutput);

x=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
if (x[i].nodeType==1)
  {//Process only element nodes (type 1) 
  var divOutput = document.createElement("div");
  var divstr = document.createTextNode(x[i].nodeName);
  divOutput.appendChild(divstr);
  outputDiv.appendChild(divOutput);
  } 
}
```

---

I want to get output something like the following

```
items
   |
   |__fruits
   |    |_____orange
   |    |_____Banana
   |    |_____Mango
   |
   |__drinks
```

Comment: This link has a similar function: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp You'll have to load in the xml file you're using first. Once loaded in, you can pull the different bits of info you need from the nodes and display them on the HTML page how you'd like, as in my examples above. Try to load in the xml file, get one of the nodes displaying the image, and you'll be on your way. Let me know other specifics that you need, and I'll gladly try to help more.